# Finding global maximum for the function $f(x) = |x| + x^2 - 3x + 1$ in $[-1, 4]$

Tags: functions

$f(x)=|x|+x^2-3x+1$

Determine the lowest and highest value of $f(x)$ on the interval $[-1, 4]$.

I assume that lowest and highest values are the global minimum and global maximum, respectively, of $f(x)$. I have found out that global minimum is $0$ at $x=1$, but I have to answer for the global maximum as well. Since it is a second degree polynomial, I thought there were no global maxima, but I guess I should use the given interval of $[-1, 4]$.

Could someone please explain this to me?

Comment: Your function is continuous on a closed interval of finite length, so it certainly has a global max and min.  Find them by testing endpoints and critical points, but realize $x=0$ is critical because it is (a) in the domain of $f$ but (b) $f'(0)$ fails to exist.

Comment: This is not a [polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial) because it involves taking the absolute value of a variable.

Answer (score 2):

We must break the set $[-1,4]$ into a union of the form $[-1,0] \cup [0,4]$, and analyse the resulting function on each of these intervals.

On $[-1,0]$, the function is $x^2 - 4x+1 = (x-2)^2 -3$. Since we are finding the maximum, this is achieved at $x = -1$, and the value is $6$, and the minimum is at $x=0$, with the value $1$.

On $[0,4]$, the function is $x^2 -2x+1 = (x-1)^2$. This attains it's maximum when $x$ is furthest from $1$ i.e. at $x=4$ with the value $9$. At $x = 1$, it attains the value $0$.

It is thus seen that the maxima and minima are attained at the points $x=4,1$ respectively, with the values $9,0$ in that order.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't bet how the function changes for [-1, 0] and [0,4]. If  I instead have f(x)=|x|+x^2-5x+6, interval [-1, 4]

Comment: S/he is breaking it up piecewise.  Just as $|x|$ is piecewise around $0$, you can use that to similarly digest $[-1,4]$ into pieces.  On the left of $0$, $|x|$ will be $-x$, and on the right it will just be $x$.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, Randall. Also, I am a boy.

Comment: Okay I'm starting to get this now. If I instead have function f(x)=|x|+x^2-5x+6, is global maximum at 13 and global minimum at 2?

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct, in the interval $[-1,4]$.